# Is it possible to dynamically set flow type of a function in an object to the type of one of its properties?

Tags: reactjs, flowtype

Consider a config of type:

```
type Config = {
  props: any,
  isEnabled?: (args: { custom: string, props: any }) => boolean,
};
```

I want to use this `Config type` such that any changes to it will apply to all its subtypes. I am able to do this as:

```
type ConfigAProps = {
  propA: boolean
}

type ConfigBProps = {|
  propsB: string
|}

type ConfigA = {|
  ...Config,
  props: ConfigAProps
|}

type ConfigB = {|
  ...Config,
  props: ConfigBProps
|}
```

Now the `isEnabled` in `type Config` still has argument of `props:any`. Is there a way to specify that the type of props in isEnabled is the same type as props field in the object (sort of like this.props)?
Or is there a better way to model these types?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want to use generics here. Instead of splatting `Config`, instead do:

```
type Config<T> = {
  props: T,
  isEnabled?: (args: { custom: string, props: T }) => boolean,
};

type ConfigA = Config<ConfigAProps>;
```

Comment: Thanks so much. Seems like I hadn't quite understood generics and this answer really helped.